# Matlab Integration - modbus.config error

Tags: volttron

The steps did successfully :

- Install the master driver
- Storing the registry file (catalyst371.csv) file
- I created modbus.config file in the main volttron root with below information:

{
    "driver_config": {"device_address": "127.0.0.2", “port”: “5020”},
    "driver_type": "modbus",
    "registry_config":"config://registers.csv",
    "interval": 5,
    "timezone": "UTC"
}

When I store the config using:

vctl config store platform.driver devices/mysite/mybuilding/modbus1 modbus.config

I get the error attached [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSS3e.png)

I also attached the Volttron Central installed components [Volttron Central](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gNXN.png) please let me know if I am missing any other agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key port and value 5020 are not enclosed within regular double quotes. They are curly quotes (may be from word or another software?). Once I fixed the quotes character around port and 5020 I was able to add the file to config store.

Comment: Also, in this case 5020 does not need to be a string. The modbus driver will accept a number here.